# Why is the intersection of this indexed set a closed interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I= \mathbb Z_+$. Let $B_i=(-1-\frac{1}{i},1+\frac{1}{i})$. The union of $\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} B_{i}=(-2,2)$ but why is $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I} B_{i}=[-1,1]$? How did we get to a closed interval?

Comment: Because $[-1,1]\subseteq B_i$ for each $i\in\Bbb Z^+$, but if $x<-1$ or $x>1$, then there is an $i\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\notin B_i$.

Comment: In fact, every closed set in $\Bbb R$ can be written as a countable intersection of open sets. It's not surprising to find a special case of this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** the interval $[-1,1]$ is contained in each $B_i$, hence it should be contained in their intersection. But for any *other* point $x \not \in [-1,1]$, can't you find some $B_i$ such that $x \not \in B_i$? Maybe doing some drawings can help to get a mental picture of the phenomenon.